# How can I auto start a python/pyside GUI

Tags: python, qt, debian

I created a Pyside QT GUI app (Python 2.7) and part of the spec is to launch it automatically when the system starts.  Normal init.d stuff doesn't seem to work since it's a GUI app.

So far I've tried x11 init.d and xdg xyz.desktop solutions and they don't seem to work.

How would you solve this?

How are Pyside apps auto started on system boot?

(Debian Wheezy)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually strange that `init.d` didn't work. You can also try to add a command into `/etc/rc.local`
Some details are here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49635

> The script /etc/rc.local is for use by the system administrator. It is
>   executed after all the normal system services are started, at the end
>   of the process of switching to a multiuser runlevel. You might use it
>   to start a custom service, for example a server that's installed in
>   /usr/local.

Comment: init.d would work with a pyside gui app?  I even tried to launch from x-11 init and nothing.  I couldn't find any meaning full boot log entries either.  So assume all syntax, permissions etc are correct would you expect a pyside gui app to successfully launch from init.d in x-11 or etc/init.d?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after hours and hours of fooling around I figured it out.  I actually used the built-in startup manager in GNOME.  I tried this before but it didn't work.  So this time I created an entry to start gnome-calculator.. the built in calculator.

Then I edited the entry in ~/.config/autostart/gnome-calculator.desktop using gedit (gedit ~/.config/autostart/gnome-calculator.desktop).  I changed Exec=gnome-calculator to Exec=python /home/me/myapp.py

and it works.

Yes it is a lame solution and it doesn't identify what the problem was but it's a start.  Thanks for the help.